# HTML5 - section element is no styling hook?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I've heard that the HTML5 `section` element should not be used for styling purposes as its a semantic element. So `<section class='wrapper'>` as a replacement for a div would be wrong, using `<div class='wrapper'>` would be better.
But what when it makes sense to use the section element **AND** there is need for wrapper? Is it alright to do `<section class='wrapper'>` in that cases? Or do I have to to

```
<section>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    ..
  </div>
</section>
```

which seems a bit bloated to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've heard that the HTML5 `section` element should not be used for styling purposes

Not sure what your source is, but they're wrong. Style away!

That being said, `<section>` elements should be used when they're semantically *appropriate*, as per the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-section-element):

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading.

Comment: +1: The reason why these new semantic elements were created was specifically because web designers always create CSS classes named like them. Now you don't need these classes anymore, because you can style the tags directly.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section

> The  element represents a generic section of a document or
>   application.
>
> - A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content:
>
>   - chapter
>   - various tabbed pages in a tabbed dialog box
>   - numbered sections of a thesis
> - A Web site's home page could be split into sections for an
>     introduction, news items, and contact information.
> - The section element is not a generic container element. The section
>     element is appropriate only if the contents would be listed explicitly
>     in the document's outline. [Example A]
> - A section typically with a heading.

You can use `<section class='wrapper'>` because adding a class is semantics, it's not styling purposes. But of course, then you can style the class.

Then, you should use `<section class='wrapper'>` if the wrapper is something big and important (if it contains a section). If not, better use `<div class='wrapper'>`.

But

```
<section>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    ..
  </div>
</section>
```

it's very awful because you add unnecessary code, which is not semantic.